# Iterate through array of hashes and merge

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I have an array of hashes like so:

```
[{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}, 
 {:a=>"a", :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"}]
```

I want to iterate over the hash and merge them where a specific key is the same, such as :a. If the next key element is the same - ignore it, but if the key is different, create an array. Result will look something like this:

```
{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>["c","notc"], :d=>"d"}
```

I think I have do a for loop through the array of hashes and then use the `merge!` method, but not sure where to start

Comment: Why do you want `:a => "a"` as a result, but `:d => ["d"]`? How do you distinguish between these cases?

Comment: What does "the next key element" mean? Hashes do not need, and will rarely have, their keys in an order, except their insertion order. If you iterate the hash you will often get a different order than if you iterate a sorted list of the hashes keys. Also, what have you tried? It's expected you'll show us your attempt so we can help you fix it, rather than us write something for you and you shoehorn it into place.

Comment: @lurker that was a typo, I've fixed it now

Comment: Why is `:b`'s value not `["b", nil]`?

Comment: Further to @sawa's point, to make the desired result consistent with the example, please: 1) change  `:b=>nil` in the second hash to `:b=>"b"` or 2) change `:b=>"b"` in your output hash to `["b",nil]`. I suppose you could also explain you don't want `nil` (or duplicate values) merged, but then you'd also have to explain if you want `:b=>nil` retained if no other hash has a key `:b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also use [Hash#merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `update`), like this (letting `a` denote the name of your array of hashes):

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g) do |_,o,n|
    case o
    when Array
      o.include?(n) ? o : o + [n]
    else
      o.eql?(n) ? o : [o,n] 
    end
  end
end
  #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>["b", nil], :c=>["c", "notc"], :d=>"d"}
```

When `o` is an array, if you don't want to merge `nil` values, change the following line to:

```
(o.include?(n) || n.nil?) ? o : o + [n]
```

The steps:

```
a = [{:a=>"a",  :b=>"b", :c=>"c",    :d=>"d"}, 
     {:a=>"a",  :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"},
     {:a=>"aa", :b=>"b", :c=>"cc",   :d=>"d"},
]

enum = a.each_with_object({})
  #-> #<Enumerator: [{:a=>"a",  :b=>"b", :c=>"c",    :d=>"d"},
  #                  {:a=>"a",  :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"},
  #                  {:a=>"aa", :b=>"b", :c=>"cc",   :d=>"d"}]
  #    :each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the values of the enumerator (which will be passed into the block) by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[{:a=>"a",  :b=>"b", :c=>"c",    :d=>"d"}, {}],
  #    [{:a=>"a",  :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"}, {}],
  #    [{:a=>"aa", :b=>"b", :c=>"cc",   :d=>"d"}, {}]]
```

Pass in the first value and assign it to the block variables:

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}, {}] 
g #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"} 
h #=> {}
```

`update`'s block is used for determining the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. As `h` is presently empty (`{}`), it is not used for this merge:

```
h.update(g)
  #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}
```

The new value of `h` is returned.

Now pass the second value of `enum` into the block:

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:a=>"a", :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"},
  #    {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c",    :d=>"d"}] 
g #=>  {:a=>"a", :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"} 
h #=>  {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c",    :d=>"d"}
```

and execute:

```
h.update(g)
```

When `:a=>"a"` from `g` is to be merged, `update` sees that `h` contains the same key, `:a`. It therefore defers to the block to determine the value for `:a` in the merged hash. It passes the following values to the block:

```
k = :a
o = "a"
n = "a"
```

where `k` is the key, `o` (for "old") is the value of `k` in `h` and `n` (for "new") is the value of `k` in `g`. (We're not using `k` in the block, so I've name the block variable `_` to so signify.) In the `case` statement, `o` is not an array, so:

```
o.eql?(n) ? o : [o,n]
  #=> "a".eql?("a") ? "a" : ["a","a"] 
  #=> "a"
```

is returned to returned to `update` to be the value for `:a`. That is, the value is not changed.

When the key is `:b`:

```
k = :b
o = "b"
n = nil
```

Again, `o` is not an array, so again we execute:

```
o.eql?(n) ? o : [o,n] 
  #=> ["b", nil]
```

but this time an array is returned. The remaining calculations for merging the second element of `enum` procede similarly. After the merge:

```
h #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>["b", nil], :c=>["c", "notc"], :d=>"d"}
```

When `:c=>"cc"` in the third element of `enum` is merged, the following values are passed to `update`'s block:

```
_ :c
o = ["c", "notc"]
n = "cc"
```

Since `o` is an array, we execute the following line of the `case` statement:

```
o.include?(n) ? o : o + [n]
  #=> ["c", "notc", "cc"]
```

and the value of `:c` is assigned that value. The remaining calculations are performed similarly.

Comment: Unfortuantely your results does not match the requirements for the `:b` key. The OP wants `:b=>"b"`.

Comment: @spickermann, I noticed that after reading @sawa's comment, and showed the required adjustment above ("When `o` is an Array,..."). I also left a comment on the question, suggesting the OP clarify.

Comment: You are right, the requirements are not clear on how `nil` values should be handled. I hope the OP clearifies this question.

Comment: If I could extra points for breadth and clarity I would. Wow!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
array = [{ :a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c",    :d=>"d" }, 
         { :a=>"a", :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d" }]

result = array.reduce({}) do |memo, hash|
  memo.merge(hash) do |_, left, right|
    combined = Array(left).push(right).uniq.compact
    combined.size > 1 ? combined : combined.first
  end
end

puts result
#=> { :a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>["c", "notc"], :d=>"d" }
```

`Array(left)` will ensure that the value of the one hash is an arary. `push(right)` adds the value from the other hash into that array. `uniq.compact` removes `nil` values and duplicates.

The `combined.size > 1 ? combined : combined.first` line returns just the element if the array holds only one element.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `hs = [{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}, {:a=>"a", :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"}]`, you can do that with a (admittedly, terribly dense) one-liner:

```
Hash[hs.map { |h| h.map { |k,v| [k, v] } }.sort_by(&:first).reduce { |left,right| left.zip(right) }.map { |a| [a.first.first, a.map(&:last).compact.uniq] }]
```

To unpack what's going on here:

First we use `map` to convert the array of hashes into an array of arrays of pairs, and then use `sort_by` to sort the array so that all of the keys are 'lined up'.

`[{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}, {:a=>"a", :b=>nil, :c=>"notc", :d=>"d"}]` becomes

`[[[:a, "a"], [:b, "b"], [:c, "c"], [:d, "d"]], 
 [[:a, "a"], [:b, nil], [:c, "notc"], [:d, "d"]]]`

That's this part:

```
 hs.map { |h| h.map { |k,v| [k, v] } }.sort_by(&:first).
```

Then, we use `reduce` and zip all the arrays together, `zip` just takes two arrays `[1,2,3]`, `[:a,:b,:c]` and outputs an array like: `[[1,:a],[2,:b],[3,:c]]`

```
    reduce { |left,right| left.zip(right) }.
```

At this point we've grouped all the data together by key, and need to de-duplicate all the copies of the key, and we can remove the nils and uniq the values:

```
    map { |a| [a.first.first, a.map(&:last).compact.uniq] }]
```

Here's a sample from a pry session:

```
[31] pry(main)> Hash[hs.map { |h| h.map { |k,v| [k, v] } }.sort_by(&:first).reduce { |left,right| left.zip(right) }.map { |a| [a.first.first, a.map(&:last).compact.uniq] }]
=> {:a=>["a"], :b=>["b"], :c=>["c", "notc"], :d=>["d"]}
```

Comment: I almost feel like this should be in CodeGolf.SE

Comment: Rather than submit something that convoluted, why not break it down into something a lot more easily understood for the benefit of the OP. Explain why it works. After all, you're supposed to be helping educate, not obfuscate a solution. And, if it being a one-liner is important, then explain why, otherwise break it into multiple lines for readability.

Comment: You may have a good solution, but you are not encouraging readers to look at it. The first thing to do, which would take only a few seconds, is to break it into several lines so that the reader does not have to scroll horizontally to read it.  (Don't worry, it still qualifies as a one-liner. :-)). For example, you could put `.sort_by...` under `hs.map...`, with dots aligned, then below that, `.reduce...`, below that `map....`, etc.

Comment: It's gross, but it also shows a lot of interesting functions. I agree that it's not newbie friendly, but sometimes it's okay for them to see non-newbie friendly answers. (I'm not sanctioning trolling, just saying that sometimes taking the kid-gloves off is okay).

Comment: Also, I've seen worse written by extremely skilled, respected, and loved developers.

Comment: @theTinMan I've unpacked the one-liner and explained all the ideas that went into its construction.